# How can I get multiple averages from multiple rows using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to get the average rating (1-10) for each of 6 games that were rated.

Here is an example of the table:
[image]

I can select the average of one of the 6 games like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(overallRating), 0), COUNT(*) AS Total, gameID
FROM gameSurvey
WHERE gameID = 1
```

I want to retrieve the average rating of all 6 games?

Comment: Instead of `where`, `group by gameId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(overallRating), 0), count(*) as Total, gameID
FROM gameSurvey
GROUP BY gameID
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the query to use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(overallRating), 0), count(*) as Total, gameID
FROM gameSurvey
GROUP BY gameID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(overallRating), 0), count(*) as Total, gameID
FROM gameSurvey
GROUP BY gameID
```

Use `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else has stated, you should use group by.

What this does, as it is implied, is group together certain rows based on a given column. In this case, you want to group all gameID values into one row. Then, any aggregate functions (such as AVG) are preformed within these groups, so the average value you see in your result set, is the average value for that given group.

Here is a resource on [GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm) clause.

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(overallRating), 0), COUNT(*) AS numberOfRatings, gameID
FROM gameSurvey
GROUP BY gameID;
```

I tried to build an SQL Fiddle example for you, but it seems to be down at the moment. Hopefully this is enough information to help you moving forward, though.